# Reading txt file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to open txt file in python using following command:

`file = open("commands.txt", "r")` but getting `FileNotFoundError`.

The file is kept in python project folder.

Is there any way to get the path of base folder automatically?

Comment: use `import os` and `os.listdir('.')`

Comment: It means the file is not in the same folder where the script is. The problem is not  base path but the location of the script and the file.

Comment: Alex, txt file is in same folder where the script is.

Comment: can you share your code at least that part?

Comment: It looks like its just not in the same folder. That's what what that error means.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify path using,
First you can compute the path

```
import os
os.getcwd()
os.path.exists(direct)
```

After this, you can do,

next, you can join the path.

```
x_file = open(os.path.join(direct, "commands.txt"), "r")
```

This should work on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If the reason you want it to automatically do this is that you're going to be changing modes a lot/opening different text files you could set the path as a variable haha. So...

```
path = '/users/name/'
f = open(path + '(filename)','r')
print f.read()
```

This works, I don't know if it's what you want, but it's just what I would do ahaha.